# Nodemailer SSL and gmail problems

Tags: node.js, email, ssl, nodemailer

So I am trying to set up my app to send emails.  I set it up using my gmail account to send the emails:

```
transport = nodemail.createTransport "SMTP", {
    service: "Gmail"
    auth: {
        user: "*"
        pass: "*"
    }
}
```

However when I send my email I get the following error:

```
{ [Error: 140735167607568:error:1409210A:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_HELLO:wrong ssl version:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s3_clnt.c:869:] stage: 'init' }
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I followed the instructions to set this up exactly as they instruct on their site.  Any ideas?  Is it something wrong with nodemailer or just something weird that I am doing?

Answer (score 0):

What version of [Nodemailer](https://github.com/andris9/Nodemailer) are you using? Similar issues have been reported and probably fixed in recent version of Nodemailer. You can refer to these issues: [155](https://github.com/andris9/Nodemailer/issues/155) and [169](https://github.com/andris9/Nodemailer/issues/165).

Wasn't able to add a comment, hence this.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying it like this:

```
var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP",{
    host: "smtp.gmail.com", // hostname
    secureConnection: false,
    port: 587, // port for secure SMTP
    requiresAuth: true,
    domains: ["gmail.com", "googlemail.com"],
        auth: {
        user: "***@gmail.com",
        pass: "***"
    }
});
```